# In UIKit, how can I add a UILabel as a subview to a UITextField so that is positioned exactly where the text will be?

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to add a `UILabel` as a subview to a `UITextField`. It should to be positioned at the exact same coordinates as the normal text contents. (I am aware of `UITextField.placeholder`, but it does not fit my requirements.)

I have created a class that inherits from `UITextField` and assigned it to a text field in a storyboard. I have added the following in the `initWithCoder` method:

```
placeholderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
// set font, color, text

[placeholderLabel sizeToFit];
// This rect is useless to me :(
CGRect frame = [self textRectForBounds:placeholderLabel.bounds];

[self addSubview:placeholderLabel];
```

I could use the `initWithFrame` method, instead of `init`, or set the `UILabel`'s `frame` property but then I would need to know a `GCRect`. Do I really need to calculate it by hand based on the `UITextField`'s height, paddings, font size, and possible left view etc?

Comment: `UITextField` already has a `placeholder`. Why are you adding your own label?

Comment: Yes, explain what you are *really* trying to do, please. What is the goal?

Comment: It must remain visible as the user types to show possible (auto) completion based on the entered text

Comment: Given that, try these search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitextfield+autocomplete

Comment: so, what are you trying to do again? seriously but anyways... whatever crazy idea that it may be, I think... a `UILabel` seems like too much work to get it aligned properly. You could instead use another identical `UITextField` using the same frame/font settings as the main `textField` and make it look like the `UILabel` you want. You should, additionally, **disable** `userInteractionEnabled` and programmatically change it's text as you would for the `UILabel`. You should have this _dummy_ `textField` above the main `textField` (_obviously_) and you could set `alpha` to kinda blend it nicely

Comment: set the dummy `textField`'s style to plain, `backgroundColor` to `clearColor`, `textColor` to `redColor` and alpha value  to `0.5`. if it's for custom-style auto-completion then the overlapping text will look dark `redColor` and the auto-completion suggestion will be a meeker red color. you can utilize the `-shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate  method of `UITextField` to transfer the entered text in the main `textField` to the dummy `textField` and perform a logic in between to add auto-completion characters.

Comment: @Maddy Thanks! One of the questions leads to an example that does [something similar](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) (single autocomplete suggestion inside the text field), I'll have to study it.